# OSX - Starting up PostgreSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, sockets

Attempting to merely start PostgreSQL (which was working just fine before a restart) and get this:

**Could not start PostgreSQL server**

pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.

**The log shows the following:**
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets

Any suggestions for getting this up and running? Thanks!

Comment: The hint clearly says that port 5432 is already in use.

Comment: try stopping it first and then merely start it